# Magento2 with Mule

Tags: magento2, api, integration

I would like to ask You about integration **Magento2** with **Mule**.

Have you done something like that?
How you did integration? By using Magento's default Apis or custom one?
Have you done some base-schema-connector for projects?

Fell free to write your experience (good and bad) about that.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Mule is an ESB.

I do not have experience with it. I will give you a general answer.

For me there are two approaches :

1. You can integrate via **REST API**, default one and custom API if
   needed.
2. If you have Magento 2 Enterprise Edition, you can use Message broker
   (AMPQ) with **RabbitMQ** which is both integrated in Mule and Magento 2
   EE.

Comment: I will integrate via REST API with RabbitMQ. I am asking about more details. Concept, architecture, maybe some code ^^ But thanks for answer ;)

Comment: As I said, I do not have experience with it.